# Where is inverse tangent positive?

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

In my book when converting $.4-.2j$ into polar notation they give the answer: $.45e^{j26.6}$; however, $\arctan(\frac{-.2}{.4}) = -26.6$ according to my calculator.

Can someone attempt to thoroughly explain this to me? I would think that since $.4-.2j$ is in the fourth quadrant then it would have two angles not over $360$ that can represent it: $-26.6$ and $334$. Do you have to flip the sign of any angles outside the range $(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{-\pi}{2}$)?

Comment: It sounds like you might be wanting to use [atan2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) rather than $\arctan$.

Comment: That being said, $0.4-2i \approx 0.45\cdot e^{i\cdot (-26.6^\circ)\cdot\frac{\pi}{180^\circ}}\approx 0.45\cdot e^{i\cdot (-0.46)}$, so it sounds like your answer key has an error.  Your exponent should be in terms of radians, not degrees.  As for the question of $-26.6^\circ$ and $333.4^\circ$, they are essentially the same angle for most uses.

Comment: I believe the answer shown in your book might be wrong - missing a minus sign. $arctan(\frac{-0.2}{0.4}) \approx -26,56° \approx -0.46$ rad. Note that if we start from the positive $x$ axis and go counterclockwise, an angle of $-26,56°$ is exactly the same as an angle of $333.44°$, which is roughly your "second angle". In reality they are the same since adding a full circle ($360°$, or $2\pi$ rad) to the angle doesn't change it whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that the principal value for the argument $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ is defined in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$, therefore since $0.4-0.2j$ lies in the fourth quadrant, its polar form should be $re^{i\theta}$ with $\theta \in (-\pi/2,0)$.

Comment: Sorry I am getting conflicting responses. So it is indeed 26.6 and not -26.6? Do I just flip the sign when I am computing arctan() of angles in the third and fourth quadrant?

Comment: @Rob By convention arctan function range is $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ therefore, for $x,y\neq 0$, it returns the correct principal $Arg(z)\in(-\pi,\pi]$ for $z$ in the first and fourth quadrant otherwise we need  add $\pi$ when $z$ is in the third quadrant and subtract $\pi$ when $z$ is in th third quadrant. In that case $z$ is in the fourth quadrant therefore $\arctan$ returns the correct value for the principal argument.

Comment: @Rob As an laternative you can refer to $\arctan2$ function.

Comment: So the book is wrong then? Essentially, I just have to add pi or subtract pi if the angle my calculator gives me is putting me in the wrong quadrant?

Comment: @Rob Yes it seems there is a typo for the solution since $z$ is in the fourth quadrant therefore the angle $\theta$ must belongs to $(-\pi/2,0)$ if we are looking for the principal argument and more in general to $(-\pi/2+2k\pi,0+2k\pi)$.